# Coloring part of the text in an android TextView with a color defined in an xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I have text that I load from an external source. I can control how the external source defines the string.

```
text = "foo<font color='red'>bar</font>foo"
text2 = "foofoo<font color='red'>bar</font>foo"
```

Is there a way to specify that Android isn't supposed to use the standard CSS color red but the red I define in my `colors.xml` file?

I want to call `createColoredText(text)` and then have my TextView with the correct color.

Comment: @Nanoc : I don't want to change the color of the whole string but just part of it.

Comment: No sure if you can do that, probably its some kind of html parser that will choose the html color. i would parse it myself and replace the colors with hex strings.

Comment: To change only part of the textview you should use the SpannableString class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem myself with regex:

```
public static Spanned formatTextForTextView(String text, Context context){
    text = replaceColorForHex(text, "blue", R.color.blue, context);
    text = replaceColorForHex(text, "green", R.color.green, context);
    text = replaceColorForHex(text, "red", R.color.red, context);
    return Html.fromHtml(text);
}

private static String replaceColorForHex(
    String text,
    String colorString,
    int colorId,
    Context context
){
    String colorHex = getColorHex(colorId, context);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "(<font[^>]+color=)(['" + '"' + "]"
            + colorString
            + "['" + '"' + "])([^>]*>)"
        //Captures a <font color='colorString'> html tag.
        //Allows for additional attributes within the font
        //tag
    );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(
            sb, matcher.group(1) + colorHex + matcher.group(3));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    text = sb.toString();
    return text;
}

private static String getColorHex(int colorId, Context context){
    int colorContent = context.getResources().getColor(colorId);
    return String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colorContent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **Spannable String**

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("YOUR TEXT");        

int startIndex=7, endIndex=9;
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TEXTVIEW.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: I want to load a single string and not a string + two ints from my database. Do you have a proposal of how to modify your code for that?

Comment: @Christian: two integers are starting and ending index of your text on which you want to apply colorspan.. for ex. in my ans i want "EXT" in Blue color so i set startindex=7 and endIndex=9

Comment: Yes, but I don't have integers as input. I have one string that's supposed to be displayed.

Comment: you want to apply color to whole string?

Comment: My input is f("foo<font color='red'>bar</font>foo"). I want to have foobarfoo with bar being red (in the way my app defines red). I'm open to changing the formatting of that string, but I want to load one String and pass it around.

Comment: so to do that in above code set startindex =4 and endIndex=6 and Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("foobarfoo");

Comment: The same code should also be able to handle "foofoo<font color='red'>bar</font>foo".

Answer (score 0):

**Use Spannable String to Changing of Coloring Text in TextView.**

```
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    builder.append("My string. I ").append(" ");

   builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan
  (getApplicationContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher),builder.length() - 1,
                 builder.length(), 0);

   builder.append("Cree by Dexode test");

    builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            ds.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);


        }
    }, 30, 41, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    txt.setText(builder);
```

Comment: I would like to pass "foo<font color='red'>bar</font>foo" to this function and see bar colored red. At the moment I don't see that the code does something like this.